# Everything becomes very large

Tags: windows-8, user-interface

I don't know why everything became so large. It wasn't like that before. I tried to look in the control panel, but I still can't find the way to make it normal again.

[image]
[image]

> Windows 8, 1024 x 600, Acer netbook

Comment: First picture, bottom-right. Isn't that a magnifying glass?

Comment: @LeeTaylor - Yes, but that only show you all your apps in the start page, which won't fix anything.

Comment: I've not tried Windows 8. Isn't there a pinch-zoom? Or is that the same as the magnifying glass?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Pinch-zoom is the same as pressing that button in the corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened up the Magnifier on my Windows 8 VM, which had the effect that your pictures show - go to your Desktop and see if it is open in the tray, and possibly check the notification area / task manager.

If that doesn't work, open your Charms bar, go to Settings, and under Easy of Access on the left, turn off 'Make everything on your screen bigger'.

Comment: OMG you are a life saver! I think I accidentally turned it on before. Thank you so much.